# Extract strings followed by number with space using regex

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I have the follwing string

```
[1] weight | width | depth | 5.0 kg | 6.0 mm^3 | 10.12 cm^2
```

From that I need to extract the unit strings only

```
unit=kg
unit=mm^3
unit=cm^2
```

I tried the below regex

```
(?<unit>[^ -+0-9\\.\|\[\}\]]+)
```

But it is also giving the weight,width,depth values too. Also tried

```
(?<unit>[\D][^|]+)
```

but not worked.
I think I need to extract the strings which are followed by number and space

Can you help me on this

Comment: Is this response a list, array or full string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a character class to list the allowed characters:

```
\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?[^\S\r\n]+(?<unit>[a-z^0-9]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yMRjT9/1)

Or more specific:

```
\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?[^\S\r\n]+(?<unit>kg|[mc]m)\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9YUDrH/1)

If there should be either a pipe or the end of the string:

```
\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?[^\S\r\n]+(?<unit>[^0-9\s]\S*)(?:[^\S\r\n]+\||$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxJvzK/1)

Comment: When I tried this, It gives me the decimal values, instead of unit

    Match 1
    unit 5.0
    Match 2
    unit 6.0
    Match 3
    unit 10.12

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I found one exception case here. Some units are coming as "mm^3" and "cm^2" etc. Is it possible to include that too

Comment: So I updated like this "\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?[^\S\r\n](?<unit>[a-z^0-9]+)\b" . Hope this is correct?

Comment: @AneeshNarayanan Ok, I have also added a pattern to take the pipe or end of string into account.

Comment: I have another requirement that to extract all the int and float values from it.
say value=5.0 value=6.0 value=10.12. And for that I have the following regex. (?<value>([-+0-9\\.]+ \\/ [-+0-9\\.]+|[-+0-9\\.]+))[ ]. This was working previously. But since some unit comes with mm^3 and cm^2, these 3 and 2 are extracting as values when using the above regex. Is there any way to avoid that

Comment: @AneeshNarayanan you might do that like this for example `(?<==)(?<value>[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)` https://regex101.com/r/AEg5Wv/1

Comment: @AneeshNarayanan or like this `(?<![\^])(?<value>[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/qTh1is/1

Answer (score 1):

I have used below regex, and it is matching only unit string.

```
 \b[a-z]{2}(?:[\^]\d+)?(?!\S)\b
```

Demo link : https://regex101.com/r/AjONqR/1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is working in most of the cases. But I see there is one unit having value "mm^3", that is not working here.

Comment: Edited.  I have added for matching the power of unit.